# PLSQL calculation and month_between from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm having a problem with creating an anonymous PL/SQL code that should print out forename, lastname and age with 1 decimal (instead of sysdate I use 01-SEP-04 ddmonyyyy) from a table. The part I'm having problem with is the age. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
set serveroutput on

 declare cursor
  car_owner is select firstN, lastN, trunc(months_between(date '2004-09-01', to_date('19' || substr(pnr, 1,6), 'yyyymmdd')))/12
from carowners;

b_first carowners.firstN%type;
b_last carowners.lastN%type;
age number (3,1);

begin
 if not car_owner%isopen
  then open car_owner;
 end if;

loop 
 fetch car_owner into b_first, b_last, age;

exit when car_owner%notfound;

dbms_output.put_line (initcap(b_first || ', ' || b_last) || ', ' || age ||' years old');

       end loop;
       close car_owner;

end;
```

The ouput i get is this:

Martin, Varg, 55.4 years old
Kenny, Green, 50.6 years old
Tony, Zawicki, 39 years old
Shawon, Hassan, 33.3 years old
Sadek, Nowicki, 35.4 years old
Jane, Roberts, 45.3 years old
Terry, Mcfield, 43.4 years old
Malice, Vanzi, 23.4 years old

**What im looking for is a output like this one:**

**Martin, Varg, 55,6 years old

Kenny, Green, 50,7 years old

Tony, Zawicki, 39,1 years old

Shawon, Hassan, 33,4 years old

Sadek, Nowicki, 35,6 years old

Jane, Roberts, 45,5 years old

Terry, Mcfield, 43,6 years old

Malice, Vanzi, 23,5 years old**

Note that I need a comma and the right decimal...

Thankful for all advice and help!

Comment: How do you go from 55.4 to 55.6 or 50.6 to 50.7?  This isn't just a substitution of decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use internationalization to set the decimal point to a commma.  Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams129.htm#REFRN10126) in the documentation.

However, for a one-time solution, I would just replace `age` with:

```
trim(replace(to_char(age, '999.9'), '.', ','))
```

Comment: This will work, but first you have to do a ceil() on the age to the first decimal place.